# How to use Feature2DExtractor<TDescriptor> with EmguCV 2.4.0

Tags: sift, emgucv

I am try to using EmguCV's sift lib.
It's O.K. for me to find features from the image, i.e.

```
SIFTDetector sift = new SIFTDetector();
var features = sift.DetectFeatures();
```

Now I want to do something like tracking the features, and I think it's might be using some api like "feature2Dtracker" ...
but I can't find how to use or place the syntax with "Tdescriptor"...

I've googled for the whole official site from the EMGU, there's only an old SURF example...
Do you have any idea? 
Thanks